# How to use set and get in IPFS with Embark Framework?

Tags: ipfs, embark

I am using Embark Framework.I am trying to store a string value in IPFS and then to retrieve that string using the hash.

Contract Code (simple_storage.sol) :-

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.7;

contract SimpleStorage {
         string public storedData;
         function SimpleStorage() {
                      storedData = "hello world";
         }
         function set(string x) {
                      storedData = x;
         }
         function get() constant returns (string x) {
                     return storedData;
         }

 }
```

Index.html Code :-

```
<html>
<head>
       <title>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</title>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
       <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="container">
      <h3>Embark - SimpleStorage Demo</h3>
      <h3> 1. Set the string in the blockchain</h3>
      <div class="form-group form-inline">
           <input type="text" class="text form-control">
           <button class="set btn btn-primary">Set String</button>
     </div>
     <h3> 2. Get the current value</h3>
     <div class="form-group">
          <div>
                current value is <span class="value"></span>
          </div>
         <button class="get btn btn-primary">Get String</button>
     </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Index.js Code :-

```
EmbarkJS.Messages.setProvider('orbit',{server: 'localhost', port: '5001'});
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("button.set").click(function() {
            var value = $("input.text").val();
            EmbarkJS.Storage.saveText(value).then(function(hash) {
                     SimpleStorage.set(hash);
            });
      });
     $("button.get").click(function() {
             SimpleStorage.get().then(function(hash) {
                     EmbarkJS.Storage.get(hash).then(function(content) {
                              $(".value").html(content);
                    });
            });
  });
});
```

I am given a string as input and it returns string as output correctly.How can i verify the values stored in orbit db?

I have tried using 'ipfs' instead of 'orbit'.But the code won't get worked?What is the issue?

Comment: @samuraj jack Please help me to develop a dapp using IPFS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are mixing up `EmbarkJS.Storage` and `EmbarkJS.Messages`. You should be configuring the storage provider not the messages one:

`EmbarkJS.Storage.setProvider('ipfs',{server: 'localhost', port: '5001'});`

Comment: I have used 'ipfs' instead of 'orbit' in my index.js.How can i verify the data stored in ipfs?How can i store numerical values??Any other methods available other than saveText and uploadFile.

Comment: ```EmbarkJS.Storage.get(hash).then(function(content) {});``` Please read the readme documentation https://github.com/iurimatias/embark-framework#embarkjs---storage